# Multi-Threading - waiting for all threads to be signalled

Tags: c#, multithreading, clr, wait, waithandle

I have scenarios where I need a main thread to wait until every one of a set of possible more than 64 threads have completed their work, and for that I wrote the following helper utility, (to avoid the 64 waithandle limit on `WaitHandle.WaitAll()`)

```
    public static void WaitAll(WaitHandle[] handles)
    {
        if (handles == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handles",
                "WaitHandle[] handles was null");
        foreach (WaitHandle wh in handles) wh.WaitOne();
    }
```

With this utility method, however, each waithandle is only examined after every preceding one in the array has been signalled... so it is in effect synchronous, and will not work if the waithandles are autoResetEvent wait handles (which clear as soon as a waiting thread has been released)

To fix this issue I am considering changing this code to the following, but would like others to check and see if it looks like it will work, or if anyone sees any issues with it, or can suggest a better way ...

Thanks in advance:

```
    public static void WaitAllParallel(WaitHandle[] handles)
    {
        if (handles == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handles",
                "WaitHandle[] handles was null");
        int actThreadCount = handles.Length;
        object locker = new object();
        foreach (WaitHandle wh in handles)
        {
            WaitHandle qwH = wh;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                 delegate
                 {
                     try { qwH.WaitOne(); }
                     finally { lock(locker) --actThreadCount; }
                 });
        }
        while (actThreadCount > 0) Thread.Sleep(80);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need 64+ threads? This smells slightly IMHO.

Comment: Can you further explain how and why you use an AutoResetEvent? Does the thread not end when its work is done?

Comment: Instead of locking an object, why not use the Interlocked (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class to increment and decrement the number of active workers?

Comment: @dtb, This is generic method to handle cases where I do need 64+ trheads, and yes, I do need them... They are not all active at once (I am using threadPool with Max Threads set to whatever CLR default is ) but I have several scenarios where total threads are way more than 64... In one case I have 3000+

Comment: @dtb,   As to AutoResetEvent, I am currently NOT using this type of wait handle, and to be honest, I'd have to stretch to envision a need for it, but as this utility is generic, I want to ensure it can handle that requirement

Comment: @Justin,  Yes I could do that...  but I do not know at compile time how many threads there will be, so I'd have to count them to initialize the shared ThreadCount variable and then add the delegates to the trhead Pool queue... could work...

Comment: @Charles: this sounds a lot like you have thousands of small tasks, and you want to know when they all have finished. Waiting for thousands of ManualResetEvents or AutoResetEvents to be signalled by the tasks is not the solution here. Sure, you can try to find a workaround around the limitation, but the limitation indicates that you shouldn't be doing this in the first place. Try to find a different approach to your actual problem.

Comment: @dtb,  Yes, fyi, what's going on in the one place I am using this is that each thread is making a long-running web service request for data about a individual business resource.  The service does not have a way to request/fetch all the data in one operation, so all 3000+ requests must be made independently. Synchronously they would take over 2 hours.  By sending them asynchronously, using the ThreadPool, with MaxThreads set appropriately, get to use multiple threads on the web service, and the entire process finishes in a few minutes.. (The server gets to worry about the Load)

Comment: @dtb,  Interestingly, I am using a semaphore class to control hjow many of the queued therads are allowed to run concurrently.  after experimenting with this setting, I discovered that I had to have around 20 concurrent requests before the process time of a single request started to degrade.

Answer (score 3):

If you know how many threads you have, you can use an interlocked decrement. This is how I usually do it:

```
 {
 eventDone = new AutoResetEvent();
 totalCount = 128;
 for(0...128) {ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadWorker, ...);}
 }

 void ThreadWorker(object state)
 try
 {
   ... work and more work
 }
 finally
 {
   int runningCount = Interlocked.Decrement(ref totalCount);
   if (0 == runningCount)
   {
     // This is the last thread, notify the waiters
     eventDone.Set();
   }
 }
```

Actually, most times I don't even signal but instead invoke a callback continues the processing from where the waiter would continue. Less blocked threads, more scalability.

I know is different and may not apply to your case (eg. for sure will not work if some of thoe handles are not threads, but I/O or events), but it may worth thinking about this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but would a [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent_members(VS.100).aspx) (.NET 4.0) conceptually solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a C# or .NET programmer, but you could use a semaphore that is posted when one of your worker threads exits.  The monitoring thread would simply wait on the semaphore *n* times where *n* is the number of worker threads.  Semaphores are traditionally used to count resources in use but they can be used to count jobs completed by waiting on the same semaphore for *n* times.

Answer (score 0):

When working with lots of simultaneous threads, I prefer to add each thread's ManagedThreadId into a Dictionary when I start the thread, and then have each thread invoke a callback routine that removes the dying thread's id from the Dictionary. The Dictionary's Count property tells you how many threads are active. Use the value side of the key/value pair to hold info that your UI thread can use to report status. Wrap the Dictionary with a lock to keep things safe.

Answer (score -1):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
{
    try
    {
        using (var h = (o as WaitHandle))
        { 
            if (!h.WaitOne(100000))
            {
                // Alert main thread of the timeout
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref actThreadCount);
    }
 }, wh);
```

Comment: `qwH` is declared locally in the loop, so this is not an issue.